# Can Entity Framework combine filtering logics in multiple methods and make ONE LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

If I call the public method **GetSomeFilteredPizzas** in the below by using Entity Framework 5,

How the entity framework manages the calls to the SQL server:

- Does it apply ghe call in the public method together with all the logic in the applyFilter1 and applyFilter2 methods and **makes only one call** to SQL server?
- **Or** it retrieves some by LINW to SQL and then applies those sample filtering methods in the memory -**like combining LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Entities** upon EF's internal preferences?

Sample below

```
public IEnumerable<Pizza> GetSomeFilteredPizzas (bool isWholeGrain, bool isColdPizza)
{
    var myPizzas = Context.Pizza.Include(p => p.Ingredients).Where(p => p.IntroducedToMarketAt == null);

    myPizzas = applyFilter1(isWholeGrain, myPizzas);
    myPizzas = applyFilter2(isColdPizza, myPizzas);

    return myPizzas.ToArray();
}

private static IQueryable<Pizza> applyFilter1(bool isWholeGrain, IQueryable<Pizza> pizzas)
{
    if (isWholeGrain)
    {
        pizzas = pizzas..Where(p => p.BreadType == "WholeGrain");
    }

    else 
    {
        pizzas = pizzas..Where(p => p.BreadType == "Standard");
    }

    return pizzas;
}

private static IQueryable<Pizza> applyFilter2(bool isColdPizza, IQueryable<Pizza> pizzas)
{
    if (isColdPizza)
    {
        pizzas = pizzas..Where(p => p.TemperatureWise == "Cold");
    }

    else 
    {
        pizzas = pizzas..Where(p => p.TemperatureWise == "Hot");
    }

    return pizzas;
}
```

Comment: As long as Method is returning `IQuerable` all filters would apply to SQL Query

Answer (score 0):

The logic in your filter methods is executed before entity framework makes an effort to generate the query. EF parses the query applied to IQueryable when you ask it for the result in your case .ToArray() call at the end of GetSomeFilteredPizzas method. So both filters will be applied to your sql query in single go.

You can verify that by launching sql profiler on your database and see the query that was generated.